# C++ creating stream function like ROS_INFO_STREAM(var1 << var2 <<...)

Tags: c++, dataoutputstream, ros2

i am working with ROS and my task is to migrate existing Projects from ros1 to ros2. In ros1 stream functions like

```
ROS_INFO_STREAM(String << variable << ...)
```

exist but not in ros2, because they are not implemented yet in the rclcpp. My idea is to write a function in c++ that works with these operators and works like std::cout. But i really don't know how to implement a function like this.

Does anyone have an idea or approach?

**Solution**:
A possible solution is to define a macro like this

```
#define ROS_INFO_STREAM(logger, _msgStream) std::stringstream stream_buffer; stream_buffer << _msgStream; ROS_INFO(logger, stream_buffer.str().c_str());
```

in a separate headerfile and include it wherever it is needed.

Comment: It's very likely that `ROS_INFO_STREAM` is a macro defined in a ROS header file. That should make it simple to find the definition and look at how they do it. Then you could possibly attempt to duplicate it?

Comment: Have you tried to look into the header console.h ?

Comment: ROS_INFO_STREAM is defined in macros_generated.h at line 99 

#define ROS_INFO_STREAM(args) ROS_LOG_STREAM(::ros::console::levels::Info, ROSCONSOLE_DEFAULT_NAME, args)

Comment: Okay, so what does `ROS_LOG_STREAM` do? (That was a rhetorical question. Let's not go through this step by step - you can follow the breadcrumbs to the implementation on your own)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in ROS 2, the RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM expects a logger a the first argument. This should work similarly to the ROS 1

```
int a = 0;
int b = 1; 
RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "Value of a = " << a << ", and value of b = " << b);
```